# How to run a .sh file or .app file for every 10 minutes in mac machine?

Tags: macos

As i am a new to MAC machine, i am not aware of the .sh and .app file creation. Could anyone please let me know how to create the .sh and .app file and also please let me know how to run those files from terminal on mac machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, please let me know how to run .app file from .sh file

Answer (score 1):

To run a sh you can do :

```
sh yourscript.sh
```

You can do a bash script (.sh) in it you put a timer with the time you want and everytime this timer happen you use :

```
open -n ./yourapp.app --args -AppCommandLineArg
```

To open your application

don't forget to put the `!#/bin/bash` in the first line of your script

at the end you will have something like :

```
!#/bin/bash
while sleep 600; do
open -n ./yourapp.app --args -AppCommandLineArg
done
```

Comment: How does this make the app/script run every 10 minutes?

Comment: The OPs probably looking for a more `launchd`-type solution, hence the question is off-topic and belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com